# hi to all i am using paypal as payment gateway in my project but it give the error

Tags: paypal

i am using paypal as payment gateway in my project but it give the error like `Could not resolve host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com; No data record of requested type when redirect to paypal`

Answer (score 0):

This indicates a network error from your computer, try switching nameservers. (`api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com` resolves to `216.113.191.88` from my computer).

You can try switching nameservers to Google Public DNS at `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.